# cakePHP Assisted Form Input

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to figure out how I could create an assisted input field based on a search query. The greatest example of this would be the dropdown one sees when one begins writing something in google or facebook search bars, assisting the user's input.

My customer has requested this as a feature and I know not how to implement it within the FormHelper class. Any ideas? Perhaps where to look for the answer?

Comment: This is not really a cakephp question. Your feature is a client side requirement that most definitely will be handled by javascript.

Comment: So, the suggested dropdowns are supposed to be based on my database. You're implying that the sql queiries and the display would be handled via JS or JQeury?

Comment: Can you post some examples of the code that you've wrote while trying to implement it by yourself?

Comment: sounds like you want [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) or similar.

Comment: @user2600386 I meant that you should be focusing on how to tackle the autocomplete requirement which is out of the scope of the framework. It's like asking how to display dynamic pie charts on the user side. Sure the data is on your database and cake is gonna serve it but that is as out of cake's scope as marking your question with a mysql tag because your DB is MySQL. Once you decide on the autocomplete problem you will have some choice or guide regarding the format of your database data. If you can't get passed the latter problem, then that would qualify a cake question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is JQuery UI's Autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

It's a front-end thing done with Javascript. The only thing you need the back-end for is probably for specifying the possible options that a user has in the dropdown.

One way of doing this would just be to have an array to populate the `availableTags` parameter. For example, a static Autocomplete might have the following (taken from the example on the page linked above):

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
```

You could store the tags in an array using Cakephp, and do something like this in your View:

```
var availableTags = [
  <?php foreach ($tags_array as $tag) echo '"' . $tag . '",'; ?>
];
```